# How can insert properties on a vector tile

Tags: mapnik, vector-tiles, tile-server

I am trying to set up a web server in Node.js that serves vector tiles to be displayed in a browser using MapboxGL JS. The data for the vector tiles is stored in a Postgressql database with PostGIS plugin.

In server, I receive a geojson file and process it createing a database with next sentence:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS countries (   
  table_id SERIAL,   
  properties jsonb not null,   
  geom geometry(GeometryZ,4326),   
  primary key (table_id) 
);
```

So with data stored I can add a layer with mapbox with tiles on source: `http://localhost:8090/tiles/namelayer/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf`

```
source: {
   type: "vector",
   tiles["http://localhost:8090/tile/coropletas/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf"]
}
```

How can pass properties inside tile to work with data properties??

I read that I can use a sql on DataSource table and I do this:

```
/** CONSTANTS **/
const TILE_SIZE = 256;
const PROJECTION_STRING = '+init=epsg:3857';

/** LIBRARIES **/
var zlib = require('zlib');
var express = require('express');
var mapnik = require('mapnik');
var Promise = require('promise');
var SphericalMercator = require('sphericalmercator');

const { pool } = require('../postgressql/config');

var mercator = new SphericalMercator({
    size: TILE_SIZE
});

mapnik.register_default_input_plugins();

var app = express();

app.get('/:namelayer/:z/:x/:y.pbf', (req, res, next) => {
    var options = {
        x: parseInt(req.params.x),
        y: parseInt(req.params.y),
        z: parseInt(req.params.z),
        layerName: req.params.namelayer
    };

   const sql = `SELECT ARRAY_AGG(f) as keys FROM (SELECT jsonb_object_keys(properties) f FROM ${options.layerName} group by f) u`;
    try {
        pool.query(sql, (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    ok: false,
                    message: error
                });
            }

            const keys = (results && results.rows && results.rows.length > 0 && results.rows[0].keys && results.rows[0].keys.length >0) ? results.rows[0].keys.slice() : [];
            const sql = generateSQL(options, keys);

            makeVectorTile(options, sql).then( (vectorTile) => {
                zlib.deflate(vectorTile, (err, data) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return res.status(500).send(err.message);
                    }

                    res.setHeader('Content-Encoding', 'deflate');
                    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-protobuf');
                    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
                    return res.send(data);
                });
            });
        });
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(404).send({
            error: e.toString(),
        });
    }
});

function generateSQL(options, keys) {

    if (keys.length === 0) {
        return `select table_id, geom from ${options.layerName}`;
    } else {
        let sql = "";
        keys.forEach( key => {
            sql = sql + `(properties->>'${key}') as ${key},`;
        });
        sql = `select table_id, ${sql} geom from ${options.layerName}`
        return sql;
    }
};

function makeVectorTile(options, sql) {

    var extent = mercator.bbox(options.x, options.y, options.z, false, '3857');
    var map = new mapnik.Map(TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, PROJECTION_STRING);
    map.extent = extent;

    var layer = new mapnik.Layer(options.layerName);
    layer.datasource = new mapnik.Datasource({
        type: process.env.DB_TYPE,
        dbname: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
        // table: options.layerName,
        table: `(${sql}) as tile`,
        user: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD
    });

    layer.styles = ['default'];
    map.add_layer(layer);

    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        var vtile = new mapnik.VectorTile(parseInt(options.z), parseInt(options.x), parseInt(options.y));
        map.render(vtile, function (err, vtile) {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            console.log(`${vtile.getData().length} KB`);
            resolve(vtile.getData());
        });
    });
};

module.exports = app;
```

With previuos code If I click on feature a receive properties of each feature but I can't work with them if I want to create a choropleth layer.

And with this code If I click on feature a receive all properties of each feature and I can create a choropleth layer but I dont know why render it incorrectly.

```
var express = require('express');
var SphericalMercator = require('sphericalmercator');
var mercator = new SphericalMercator({
    size: 256 //tile size
});

const { pool } = require('../postgressql/config');

var app = express();

app.get('/:namelayer/:z/:x/:y.pbf', (req, res, next) => {
    var options = {
        x: parseInt(req.params.x),
        y: parseInt(req.params.y),
        z: parseInt(req.params.z),
        layerName: req.params.namelayer
    };
    const bbox = mercator.bbox(options.x, options.y, options.z, false, '3857');

    const sql = `
        SELECT ST_AsMVT(q, '${options.layerName}', 4096, 'geom')
        FROM (
            SELECT
                table_id, properties,
                ST_AsMVTGeom(
                    geom,
                    ST_MakeEnvelope(${bbox[0]}, ${bbox[1]}, ${bbox[2]}, ${bbox[3]}, 4326),
                    4096,
                    256,
                    false
                ) AS geom
            FROM ${'public.'+options.layerName} c
        ) q;
    `;

    try {
        pool.query(sql, (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    ok: false,
                    message: error
                });
            }

            const tile = results.rows[0];
            // set the response header content type
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-protobuf');

            // trigger catch if the vector tile has no data, (return a 204)
            if (tile.st_asmvt.length === 0) {
                res.status(204);
            }  

            // send the tile!
            res.send(tile.st_asmvt);
        });
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(404).send({
            error: e.toString(),
        });
    }
});


module.exports = app;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I solved adding properties stored in database as jsonb to tile.

```
/** CONSTANTS **/
const TILE_SIZE = 256;
const PROJECTION_STRING = '+init=epsg:3857';

/** LIBRARIES **/
var zlib = require('zlib');
var express = require('express');
var mapnik = require('mapnik');
var Promise = require('promise');
var SphericalMercator = require('sphericalmercator');

const { pool } = require('../postgressql/config');

var mercator = new SphericalMercator({
    size: TILE_SIZE
});

mapnik.register_default_input_plugins();

var app = express();

app.get('/:namelayer/:z/:x/:y.pbf', (req, res, next) => {
    var options = {
        x: parseInt(req.params.x),
        y: parseInt(req.params.y),
        z: parseInt(req.params.z),
        layerName: req.params.namelayer
    };

    const sql = `select json_data.key, jsonb_typeof(json_data.value) from ${options.layerName} x, jsonb_each(x.properties) as json_data group by key, jsonb_typeof order by key, jsonb_typeof;`
    try {
        pool.query(sql, (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    ok: false,
                    message: error
                });
            }
            const response = (results && results.rows && results.rows.length > 0 && results.rows[0]) ? results.rows.slice() : [];
            const sql = generateSQL(options, response);

            makeVectorTile(options, sql).then( (vectorTile) => {
                zlib.deflate(vectorTile, (err, data) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return res.status(500).send(err.message);
                    }

                    res.setHeader('Content-Encoding', 'deflate');
                    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-protobuf');
                    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
                    return res.send(data);
                });
            });
        });
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(404).send({
            error: e.toString(),
        });
    }
});



function generateSQL(options, response) {

    if (response.length === 0) {
        return `select table_id, geom from ${options.layerName}`;
    } else {
        let sql = "";
        response.forEach( data => {
            sql += (data.jsonb_typeof === 'null' || data.jsonb_typeof === null) ? 
                ` properties->>'${data.key}' as ${data.key},` : 
                ` cast (properties->>'${data.key}' as ${getDataBaseType(data.jsonb_typeof)}) as ${data.key},`;
        });
        sql = `select table_id, ${sql} geom from ${options.layerName}`;
        return sql;
    }
};

function getDataBaseType(typedb) {

    switch(typedb) {
        case 'string': return 'text';
        case 'number': return 'decimal';
        default: return;
    }

};

function makeVectorTile(options, sql) {

    var extent = mercator.bbox(options.x, options.y, options.z, false, '3857');
    var map = new mapnik.Map(TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, PROJECTION_STRING);
    map.extent = extent;

    var layer = new mapnik.Layer(options.layerName);
    layer.datasource = new mapnik.Datasource({
        type: process.env.DB_TYPE,
        dbname: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
        table: `(${sql}) as tile`,
        user: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD
    });

    layer.styles = ['default'];
    map.add_layer(layer);

    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        var vtile = new mapnik.VectorTile(parseInt(options.z), parseInt(options.x), parseInt(options.y));
        map.render(vtile, function (err, vtile) {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            resolve(vtile.getData());
        });
    });
};

module.exports = app;
```